# How to control the Identity Server URI's protocol in the Discovery Document

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have Identity Server 4 running on a secured endpoint. The problem I am having is that the discovery document located at `/.well-known/openid-configuration` has some of the URL's as "http" rather than "https"

```
{
"issuer": "https://identity-test.xyz.com",
"jwks_uri": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
"authorization_endpoint": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/connect/authorize",
"token_endpoint": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/connect/token",
"userinfo_endpoint": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/connect/userinfo",
"end_session_endpoint": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/connect/endsession",
"check_session_iframe": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/connect/checksession",
"revocation_endpoint": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/connect/revocation",
"introspection_endpoint": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/connect/introspect",
"device_authorization_endpoint": "http://identity-test.xyz.com/connect/deviceauthorization",
"frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
"frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
"backchannel_logout_supported": true,
"backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
"scopes_supported": [
    "roles",
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "address",
    "skoruba_identity_admin_api",
    "na-api",
    "offline_access"
],
"claims_supported": [
    "role",
    "sub",
    "name",
    "family_name",
    "given_name",
    "middle_name",
    "nickname",
    "preferred_username",
    "profile",
    "picture",
    "website",
    "gender",
    "birthdate",
    "zoneinfo",
    "locale",
    "updated_at",
    "email",
    "email_verified",
    "address"
],
"grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials",
    "refresh_token",
    "implicit",
    "password",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code",
    "delegation"
],
"response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "token",
    "id_token",
    "id_token token",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token"
],
"response_modes_supported": [
    "form_post",
    "query",
    "fragment"
],
"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
],
"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
],
"subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
],
"code_challenge_methods_supported": [
    "plain",
    "S256"
],
"request_parameter_supported": true
```

}

I believe the setting `IdentityServerOptions__IssuerUri=https://identity-test.xyz.com` is the only reason the first URL has https. I tried setting `IdentityServerOptions__RequreSsl=true` but that had no effect.

How can I get Identity Server to use the https protocol for the rest of the URL's?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the PublicOrigin option [has been removed](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4535).

We had to change the code to this:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) => {
    if (ctx != null)
    {
        ctx.SetIdentityServerOrigin(Configuration.GetSection("AdminConfiguration").GetValue<string>("IdentityServerBaseUrl"));
    }
    await next();
});
```